# Rewriting Python switch into a more compact way

Tags: python, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacements for switch statement in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Suppose I have a list in Python:

> list = ('ADD', 'SUB', 'PUSH', 'POP')

I want to run a function depending on input, and that input can be any value in the list.

Instead of writing a switch case statement for each element in `list`, is there a more compact way of writing it?

My reasoning is for the case of the list growing in the future.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/60208/562139

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't call a variable `list`, because that's the name of the built-in `list` type. (It's even more confusing in this case, because your object isn't a `list`, it's a `tuple`.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So many terms from so many languages...waaaah!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there *is* no switch/case statement in Python.

For a small `list`, you want to use `if`/`elif`:

```
def do_stuff(x, *args):
    if x == 'ADD':
        return do_add(*args)
    elif x == 'SUB':
        return do_sub(*args)
    # …
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Never heard of {}'.format(x))
```

For a larger `list`, you want to make sure each case is a function (I already assumed that above, but if you had code like `return args[0] + args[1]`, you'd have to change that into a `do_add` function), and create a `dict` mapping names to functions:

```
func_map = {'ADD': do_add, 'SUB': do_sub, … }

def do_stuff(x, *args):
    try:
        return func_map[x](*args)
    except KeyError:
        raise RuntimeError('Never heard of {}'.format(x))
```

This works because in Python, functions are normal objects that you can pass around like any other objects. So, you can store them in a `dict`, retrieve them from the `dict`, and still call them.

By the way, this is all explained in [the FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python), along with a bit of extra fanciness.

If you have some default function you'd like to call instead of raising an error, it's obvious how to do that with the `if`/`elif`/`else` chain, but how do you do it with the `dict` map? You *could* do it by putting the default function into the `except` block, but there's an easier way: just use the [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
def do_stuff(x, *args):
    return func_map.get(x, do_default)(*args)
```

Comment: @Lattyware: You had a bit of nice extra explanation, which I'll steal to improve my answer.

Comment: Instead of raising an Error for a key not found, would it work to default x?

Comment: @drum: Sure, if that's what you want, you can do that. In that case, you may want to replace the `try`/`map[x]`/`except` with a `map.get`. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a pattern such as this (in a hurry so can't clean it up atm):

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def test_FOO(self):
...             print 'foo'
...     
...     def test_BAR(self):
...             print 'bar'
... 
>>> def run_on(cls, name):
...     getattr(cls, 'test_%s' % name)()
... 
>>> run_on(Test(), 'FOO')
foo
```